# Protecting a data traveler drive's data by running anti-virus automatically on plug

Tags: anti-virus, automation, autorun

How to Protect a data traveler drive's data by running anti-virus automatically on plug.the anti-virus program must be on removable drive.Any software will be preferred on script or programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Free AVG antivirus](http://free.avg.com/ww-en/download-avg-anti-virus-free) has this option. Plus, it is an excellent free antivirus solution.

Comment: You mean it will remain in data traveler drive and whenever I plug that drive,anti-virus will run automatically,is that so ?